# Pojos extending an other class in Spring Data MVC- Endpoits

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a project, its model is to register people into the system.

- There are Patients that are extending the Pojo Person
- There are Staff members that also extend the Pojo Person
- There are Pharmacists & Office members that extend the Pojo Staff

My CRUD operations have endpoints at the Repository of the patients and the Repository of Staff.

Example: Postmapping(/patients) and Postmapping(/staff)

The question is, what do i have to do, so that my system recognizes (at the /staff) if the person who is just getting registered is a Pharmacist or an Office member? Is there any solution with the same endpoint?

Or should i create new endpoints like (/staff/pharmacist + /staff/office)?

Or should i somehow in my frontend deal with that ?